# Using LiuLiu's CCV under iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, computer-vision

I'm trying to use CCV library under IOS. I'm trying a ver simple test: open file and save it back to disk — but it doesn't work.

```
NSString *srcPath, *dstPath;
srcPath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"src" ofType:@"jpg"];
dstPath = [NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES)[0] stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"dst.jpg"];

ccv_dense_matrix_t* image = 0;
ccv_read((char*)[srcPath cStringUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding], &image, CCV_IO_JPEG_FILE);

// BREAKPOINT

ccv_write(image, (char*)[dstPath cStringUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding], 0, CCV_IO_JPEG_FILE, 0);
```

When app stops at breakpoint `image == NULL`
When app finishes I can find `dst.jpg` file, but it's size is 0 bytes.

What am i doing wrong?

I'm using `libccv.a` that I manually complied with this config:

```
XCODE_SDK := iphoneos7.0
ARCH := armv7
CC := clang
AR := ar
CFLAGS := -arch armv7 -isysroot "/Applications/Xcode 2.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS7.0.sdk" -D HAVE_LIBJPEG -I/usr/X11/include 
LDFLAGS := -lm -arch armv7 -isysroot "/Applications/Xcode 2.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS7.0.sdk" -ljpeg -lz -L/usr/X11/lib
```

I also use `libjpeg.a` that I've downloaded from github: https://github.com/swisspol/Libraries/blob/master/Libraries-iOS/libjpeg-turbo/lib/libjpeg.a

Comment: I would really like @liuliu — author of this incredible lib to see this question.